# Is there any way to open recovery mode with only hard keys?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom-flashing, custom-roms

i had flashed a custom rom on my device. But unfortunately it does not boot properly. And suddenly i have noticed that my volume keys are not working. And i had'nt debug mode opened. so now what can i do? how can i open recovery mode with only one hard key?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: And what does "does not boot properly" mean? What actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

Possible with command but there are conditions,

1. you have usb debugging enabled
2. you need to configure adb

if you have this two things configured then you can type following command to boot your phone into recovery mode

```
adb reboot recovery
```

or

```
adb shell reboot recovery
```